# Using OpenSSH Server without local user

Tags: linux, openssh, pam, radius

Currently I've noticed when I use the OpenSSH Server with PAM and for instance RADIUS while I can get the user to authenticate successfully with PAM, I still need a local user account in /etc/passwd, e.g. added with useradd on the box.

Is there any setting in OpenSSH to say there does not need to be a local user is /etc/passwd. And instead the shell/home dir/session will be initialized through some default setting? I have been unable to locate any way to do this online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The configuration in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` sets the order in which users will be looked up. You can check with `getent passwd $USER` how your user is resolved. There is no need for a user to have a local account in order to login. Bind the `passwd` and `group` databases in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` to ldap, nis and/or sss and use the proper PAM module in the stack.

A use case using [SSSD](https://fedorahosted.org/sssd/) and [freeIPA](http://www.freeipa.org), where users, groups, login shell, sudo rules, SELinux mappings, etc, are stored in the directory managed by freeIPA. Note that SSHD uses GSSAPI to authenticate against kerberos, whose database is stored in the directory as well:

```
 # cat /etc/krb5.conf
 [logging]
  default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
  kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
  admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log
 [libdefaults]
  default_realm = DOMAIN.COM
  dns_lookup_realm = false
  dns_lookup_kdc = true
  rdns = false
  ticket_lifetime = 24h
  forwardable = yes
 [realms]
  DOMAIN.COM = {
   kdc = ipaserver.domain.com:88
   master_kdc = ipaserver.domain.com:88
   admin_server = ipaserver.domain.com:749
   default_domain = domain.com
   pkinit_anchors = FILE:/etc/ipa/ca.crt
 }
 [domain_realm]
  .crapsteak.org = DOMAIN.COM
  crapsteak.org = DOMAIN.COM
 [dbmodules]
   DOMAIN.COM = {
     db_library = ipadb.so
   }
```

# grep sss /etc/nsswitch.conf
 passwd:     files sss
 shadow:     files sss
 group:      files sss
 services:   files sss
 netgroup:   files sss
 automount:  files sss

# cat /etc/sssd/sssd.conf
 [domain/domain.com]
 cache_credentials = True
 krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
 ipa_domain = domain.com
 id_provider = ipa
 auth_provider = ipa
 access_provider = ipa
 ipa_hostname = somehost.domain.com
 chpass_provider = ipa
 ipa_server = ipaserver.domain.com
 ldap_tls_cacert = /etc/ipa/ca.crt
 [sssd]
 services = nss, pam, ssh
 config_file_version = 2
 domains = domain.com

# grep sss /etc/pam.d/{password,system}-auth-ac
 /etc/pam.d/password-auth-ac:auth        sufficient    pam_sss.so use_first_pass
 /etc/pam.d/password-auth-ac:account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_sss.so
 /etc/pam.d/password-auth-ac:password    sufficient    pam_sss.so use_authtok
 /etc/pam.d/password-auth-ac:session     optional      pam_sss.so
 /etc/pam.d/system-auth-ac:auth        sufficient    pam_sss.so use_first_pass
 /etc/pam.d/system-auth-ac:account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_sss.so
 /etc/pam.d/system-auth-ac:password    sufficient    pam_sss.so use_authtok
 /etc/pam.d/system-auth-ac:session     optional      pam_sss.so

# grep GSS /etc/ssh/sshd_config
 GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
 GSSAPIAuthentication yes

Comment: Thanks that helps a lot but in my case I really don't care about the user home/shell on a per user basis. All user can use the same home and they will all use the same shell. I'm curious if you have a suggestion on the correct database to use in a case like that. I don't  want to have the burden of the user having to setup and add all the users to an ldap server etc... Any suggestions?

Comment: You don't really have to. You define a default shell (and additionally a default SELinux user mapping, default group, etc...) in the provided schema. The freeIPA team has gone to great lenghts to provide a very comprenhensive schema. Alternatively, there are PAM modules for almost anything you can think of. It is a matter of scale, maybe.

Comment: Just a follow up it seems pam alone isn't sufficient for this. I was hoping that using pam_radius for auth/account and pam_permit for session would work but from the strace it looks like sshd still calls with nsswitch.conf. While sssd and freeipa seem nice in my use case they will be too heavy handed. I can't require someone to have a server running those. So far it seems the best solution is to implement a nss module that works for passwd by returning a default /etc/passwd string no matter who is called. Can you think of any other better light weight option?

Comment: From some quick searchs, it looks like everybody complains of a missing libnss_radius addition to glibc to be able to add the service to the nsswitch. The lighweight option would be a Lightweight Directory Access Protocol backend for your Radius server, I'm afraid.